# Getting rest call exception "PKIX path building failed"

Tags: apex, rest-api, soap-api

I am getting an exception while calling Rest API 
"PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target"

My Code is :

```
HttpResponse res = request('https://api.test.com/test');
System.debug(res);

  public HTTPResponse request(String path){
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    Http http = new Http(); 
    req.setEndpoint(path);
    req.setMethod('GET');
    req.setClientCertificatename('api_expocad_com');
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/JSON;charset=UTF-8');
    req.setHeader('User-Agent', 'salesforce-desk-client/0.1.0');
    req.setHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
    req = basicAuthentication(req);
    HttpResponse res2 = http.send(req);
    return res2;
  }

  private HTTPRequest basicAuthentication(HTTPRequest req1){
    Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf('Test1:Test2');
    req1.setHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue));
    return req1;
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

The error suggests that the certificate being used by the remote host isn't signed by a certificate authority (CA) that is trusted by Salesforce. If it is a web service that you are hosting you could look at changing the certificate.

See [SSL certificates Salesforce supports](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000007225&language=en_US) and [Outbound Messaging SSL CA Certificates](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Outbound_Messaging_SSL_CA_Certificates)

With the actual URL of the web service you could use https://www.digicert.com/help/ the get the SSL certificate details.